# Explode on new line in PHP only reads first line

Tags: php, arrays, newline, explode

So my input is a number of lines :

```
AAAAA
CCSDCSDC
jhbhvhv
```

I use explode in PHP to have an array, each array entry is a  line:

```
$lines=explode("\n", $text);
```

so when I do this

```
echo $lines[0];
echo $lines[1];
echo $lines[2];
```

I get only the first line :

```
AAAAA
```

What goes wrong ?

Comment: https://eval.in/57555 ?

Comment: samitha same problem when using a loop, @hal9000 it wont work for me :\

Comment: Could you please supply a more exact / non-obscured code?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$str = "AAAAA\nCCSDCSDC\njhbhvhv";

$lines=explode("\n", $str);

echo $lines[0]."<br/>";
echo $lines[1]."<br/>";
echo $lines[2]."<br/>";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but does it make a diffrence where the php script is running on?

I mean \n for UNIX systems and \r\n for Windows. Maybe you could try this:

```
$lines=explode("\r\n", $text);
```